# Find a formula for $g'''(a)$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ has third derivation on $\mathbb R$ and for a real number $a$, $f(a)=a$ and $f'(a)=-1$.
Suppose that $g(x)=f(f(x)).$
 Find the value of $g'(a)$ and $g''(a)$.
Find a simple formula for $g'''(a)$.

Note :  According to the formula for derivation of combination of two functions, I calculated $g'(a)=1$.

Comment: I don't see how it is possible that $f(a)=a$ everywhere and $f'(a) = -1$. Is there a mistake?

Comment: The part about "for each real number $a$" doesn't really make sense here. Maybe the problem is rather the following: suppose $f$ is three times differentiable and that $a$ satisfies $f(a)=a$ and $f'(a)=-1$. Find the values of...

Comment: @Maryam Seraj $g''(a)=0$ so $g'''(a)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

We have g''(x)=f''(f(x)).f'(x)^2+f'(f(x)).f''(x)

g''(a)=f''(a)-f''(a)

g''(a)=0

& similarly calculating g'''(x) , we get

g'''(a)=-2f'''(a)-3f''(a)^2

Answer (score -1):

We have, by the chain rule: $g'(x)=f'(f(x))f'(x)$. Hence

$$ g'(a)=f'(f(a))f'(a)=f'(a)^2=1.$$

Now its your turn to compute $g''(a)$ and $g'''(a)$.

Comment: i already knew that sir ...

Comment: OOhoo ! What else was your question(s) , Madam ?